# How can store a file on Google Storage from URL on Google App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, boto, google-cloud-storage

I want to create a service on Google App Engine (Python) that will receive a URL of an image and store it on Google Storage. I managed to upload from a local file using `boto` or `gsutil` command line, but not by retrieving the file via URL. I tried doing it using the [HTTP requests (`PUT`)](http://code.google.com/apis/storage/docs/reference-methods.html#putobject) and I'm getting error responses for wrong signatures. Obviously I'm doing something wrong, but unfortunately I have no idea where.

So my question is: How can I retrieve a file from a URL and store it on Google Storage using Python for Google App Angine?

Here is what I've done (using another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3822385/google-storage-api-put-file-problem-in-python/3837802#3837802)):

```
class ImportPhoto(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        srow = self.response.out.write
        url = self.request.get('url')
        srow('URL: %s\n' % (url))
        image_response = urlfetch.fetch(url)
        m = md5.md5()
        m.update(image_response.content)
        hash = m.hexdigest()
        time = "%s" % datetime.utcnow().strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT")
        str_to_sig = "PUT\n" + hash + "\n\n" + 
                      time + "\nx-goog-acl:public-read\n/lipis/8418.png"
        sig = base64.b64encode(hmac.new(
                                  config_credentials.GS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
                                  str_to_sig, hashlib.sha1).digest())
        total = len(image_response.content) 
        srow('Size: %d bytes\n' % (total))

        header = {"Date": time,
                  "x-goog-acl": "public-read",
                  "Content-MD5": hash,
                  'Content-Length': total,
                  'Authorization': "GOOG1 %s:%s" % 
                                    (config_credentials.GS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, sig)}

        conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("lipis.commondatastorage.googleapis.com")
        conn.set_debuglevel(2)

        conn.putrequest('PUT', "/8418.png")
        for h in header:
            conn.putheader(h, header[h])
        conn.endheaders()
        conn.send(image_response.content + '\r\n')
        res = conn.getresponse()

        srow('\n\n%d: %s\n' % (res.status, res.reason))
        data = res.read()
        srow(data)
        conn.close()
```

And I'm getting as a response:

```
URL: https://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/8418.png
Size: 9605 bytes

400: Bad Request
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><Error><Code>BadDigest</Code><Message>The Content-MD5 you specified did not match what we received.</Message><Details>lipis/hello.jpg</Details></Error>
```

Comment: Can you post some code that does the POU and the server reply?

Comment: @Peter Knego I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you read the docs on [how to sign requests](http://code.google.com/apis/storage/docs/developer-guide.html#authentication)? The string to sign must include the `Content-MD5`, `Content-Type` and `Date` headers, in addition to the custom headers and the resource path.

Comment: I did but I can't get it to work. Can you give me an example that I could try?

Comment: You're not including those headers in the string you sign in the example code you gave. Try adding them as documented, and if it still doesn't work, show us the code that you're using then.

Answer (score 1):

`Content-MD5` header is optional for [PUT requests](http://code.google.com/apis/storage/docs/reference-methods.html#putobject). Try leaving this out for a test.

Also, required headers are `Authorization`, `Date` and `Host`. It seems that your request is missing `Host` header.

Comment: When I added the host I was still getting the same error. When I removed Content-MD5 then I'm getting a *403: Forbidden* _The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your Google secret key and signing method._

Comment: Try using Chrome Potster or Firefox Poster plugins to manually create PUT requests. Check with various headers until you get it right. Then transfer this to code. https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/cdjfedloinmbppobahmonnjigpmlajcd?hl=en  https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2691/

Comment: can't make it to work. I think my signature is wrong so I can't get that right to put it on Poster :( Do I make any sense in the above code on how to calculate it?

Comment: I develop in Java on AppEngine so I can't comment on Python. It seems correct. But if you can't get Poster to work then maybe you should recheck other header parameters, like Host and Authentication.